# Running IIS Application with different user Credentials

Tags: security, iis

I have deployed an application on IIS Server and Servlet Exec configured.  I need run the application with windows User Credentials rather than Anonymous User. I tries changing the username and password of annonmous user in properties/Security but the application stops responding changing it back to default Anonymous IIS user account works fine??

Abdul Khaliq

Answer (score 5):

If it is on iis 6 or greater, there is a place you can create application pools. If you don't have a dedicated application pool for your application yet, create one. While creating you can set the default identity it should work with. You can set it to system defaults or a custom identity you've created...

Comment: No, I have IIS 5.1 with Windows XP

Answer (score 4):

You should change the identity for the application pool (not the website). So it's best to create a specific application pool for every site which needs specific user credentials.

But this question really belongs on serverfault.com